# Diferent workitems producing identical data

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

We divide big Revit models into small parts and export them in parallel on Forge Design Automation. We also use Forge Object Storage Service to store the input and output for every workitem. I have noticed that the workitems that are submitted close to each other, end up producing the same result. Basically, when I download the result from the Object Storage, it's the same content. I am generating separate upload URLs and have checked to make sure there is no issue there. From the logs, I am also fairly confident that the plugin uploads different content for those workitems. So not sure why the result from the two workitems are the same.  Here are the IDs for the two workitems producing identical results:

```
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2022-10-12T19:57:01.995821Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2022-10-12T19:57:02.1160281Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2022-10-12T19:57:03.781645Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2022-10-12T19:58:25.6715461Z",
    "timeUploadEnded": "2022-10-12T19:58:26.3238963Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 37369723,
    "bytesUploaded": 9439120
  },
  "id": "3fa393f23dcf4795a06618a994cabe30"
```

and:

```
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2022-10-12T19:57:45.3658136Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2022-10-12T19:57:45.4783002Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2022-10-12T19:57:57.4772213Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2022-10-12T19:59:12.4662698Z",
    "timeUploadEnded": "2022-10-12T19:59:13.2390646Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 366121473,
    "bytesUploaded": 13414340
  },
  "id": "59bfd8f36f0043338072ccc520a9a108"
```

Let me know if there is more information I should share.

Comment: I will check both WorkItems, and get back to you.

Comment: These two WorkItems were processed in different machines. We masked the URL for the uploads in our log for security, so I cannot tell the differences in URLs for the uploads between these two WorkItems. But I noticed both WorkItems worked on the same Revit model named as `gPOR4.3-ALL-PIM.rvt`. Could you double check if the inputs of these two WorkItems are the same?

Comment: Hi Emma, I can share the upload URL over email. All the workitems share the same root Revit model, but they have different linked documents, so that's why you see the same Revit model name. I updated the question with stats from the workitems, as you can see different number of bytes were downloaded and uploaded, so it implies they use two different models.

Comment: Ehsan, now I see about the same Revit model part. It looks Design Automation did upload something different for these two WorkItems. Please share the upload URLs via `forge.help@autodesk.com`, so we can check from Forge Object Storage Service teams. Thanks.

Comment: Shared the logs and the upload URLs through the email address.

Comment: thanks, Ehsan. I will reach out Forge Object Storage Service team and get back to you. A quick question: does this issue just happen recently?

Comment: I had seen it in the past occasionally, but it went away and I thought it was related to some of the changes that we made to the code. But I noticed it's back again last week and haven't been able to find a way to go around it this time.

Comment: Ehsan, I have post what we found from Forge Object Storage Service team 4 days ago, did you get it? If so, is this issue resolved?